# Spring MVC: Each ControllerAdvice opening own transaction

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

My app is Spring Boot 2.3.1 using managed versions throughout for Hibernate, Spring MVC etc.

I've noticed via Hibernate debug session logging that a single page view on my application is opening and closing a session five times. This appears to be because each of my custom Spring MVC @ControllerAdvice or Filter implementations are all getting their own transaction.

I had assumed that they would all share a single transaction as they're part of the same HTTP request. However it seems it must be happening somewhere lower down.

I'm interested to know whether this is standard behaviour or whether I have something misconfigured. I'm probably leaning on the side of premature optimisation here, but borrowing and returning a connection 5 times for a single request feels like unnecessary overhead.